# PIP certificate issues OSX

Tags: python, ssl, pip

On 7/4 I started to get this error from pip on OSX

Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pytest/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pytest/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1045)'))) - skipping

I get this with any and every module I try to install with pip. This happens on python 3.6 and 3.7, in virtual and non virtual environments. I have looked at previous stackoverflow issues relating to certs and pip, and tried the various suggestions to no avail.

Openssl reports version LibreSSL 2.2.7 OSX 10.13.5. And pip is 10.0.1

Comment: I already tried everything applicable to OSX in this issue and none of it helped

Comment: Fixed by setting pip.conf correctly. Has to be in ~/Library/Application Support/pip   I had it in /Library [global]
trusted-host = pypi.python.org
               pypi.org
               files.pythonhosted.org